# How to properly constrain generated clock and synchronizer in Altera Quartus?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, timing-analysis, quartus, sdc

In my Verilog design I have a 25Mhz board clock from which I derive a 100Mhz clock. Coming from an external Pin I have an asynchronous 4.77 Mhz clock which should drive the logic and be synchronized before (using the main clock):

```
always @(posedge clk_100Mhz_i)
begin
    // Synchronizer chain... hopefully    
    clk4_del0 <= clk4_77_i; // SysClk from ext pin
    clk4_del1 <= clk4_del0;
    clk4_del2 <= clk4_del1;
end

// Used to clock internal regs
assign clock_4_77Mhz = clk4_del2;

// Sample
always @(posedge clock_4_77Mhz)
begin
    timerIdx <= timerIdx +1;
end
```

Unfortunately I get the following warning:

**Warning (332060): Node: X8255_top:x8255|clk4_del2 was determined to be a clock but was found without an associated clock assignment....**

I also get a warning about an unconstrained clock. I tried to use what the Timing Analyzer suggested and added the fourth line to my .SDC:

```
# Constrain clock port clk_25MHz_i
create_clock -period "25.0 MHz" -name clk_25MHz [get_ports clk_25MHz_i]
create_clock -period "4.77 MHz" -name clk_4_77MHz [get_ports clk_4_77_i]
create_clock -name {X8255_top:x8255|clk4_del2} -period 210
```

without success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you know and need to learn? https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/quartus-ii-clocks/

Comment: You should define the `clock_4_77Mhz` signal as clock, not the incoming `clk_4_77_i`. I am not familiar with Altera Quartus what the exact syntax is to define an internal signal as clock. Beware that due to the synchronization your mark-space ratio will be affected and thus can be shorter then 209ns.

Comment: Try posting FPGA QUESTION [HERE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125912/fpga?referrer=M2EwM2FlOWQwMWY3MmExMzFhMGYzYjdhMmZjNWIzYzI2ZTZiZjhmNGU4Y2M4M2JjNDgxZjQyYTIyMzA2MWUwNzX3hnbYNR7EdlfF6m4rBq-JYXjqFwvBDZB5QkiDqKuf0)

Answer (score 0):

Likely, it is because `clk4_del2` is not used as a clock (e.g. connected to a clock input of a DFF), but as an intermediate signal... you may even find it gets optimized-out (in your reports?) as it is a continuous assignment.  Unless you use a primitive (clock buffer maybe) and tell the tool not to remove the buffer, and thus the buffer contributes to path delay (and it forces a "name change"), I don't think it will resolve as you intend.

**Alternatives, you probably realize already and are only asking because want to keep the RTL as-is, but jic:**

If you were to replace your `clk_4_77MHz` clocked process with `clk4_del2` you should find that the constraint resolves properly....  but, then you have the dangling net of `clk_4_77_MHz` (assuming it isn't used anywhere else) and that is kind of ugly.

If you like your `clk_4_77MHz` (i.e. it is more descriptive), eliminate the `clk4_del2` and replace the assignment: `clk4_del2 <= clk4_del1` with `clk_4_77MHz <= clk4_del1`.

Either that, or just leave everything the way it is and remove the constraint for `clk4_del2`, and your intent, and the tool's interpretation of your intent, should remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

The 4.77 MHz input is declared as a clock, but then used as a DFF input, and a bit later you are trying to use a DFF output as a clock again.

That is not how a synchronizer chain works, however. The output from the DFF is synchronous to the 100 MHz clock, but only at the exit of the DFF, so the only meaningful thing you can do with it is feed it (maybe through some combinatorics) into another DFF that is clocked with 100 MHz.

Trying to use it as a clock creates a routing nightmare first (because handover points into the clock networks are rare to nonexistant), and the result would not be anything with a fixed phase relationship to the 100 MHz clock.

Instead, you want to edge detect at the end of your synchronizer chain, and then take over data from the 4.77 MHz clock domain into the 100 MHz clock domain when you detect a rising edge.

In VHDL:

```vhdl
    port(
        clk477 : in std_logic;
        data477 : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        clk100 : in std_logic;
        …
    );
```

```vhdl
    signal clk477_r, clk477_rr, clk477_rrr : std_logic;
    signal enable477 : std_logic;

    signal data : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
…
    clk477_r <= clk477 when rising_edge(clk100);
    clk477_rr <= clk477_r when rising_edge(clk100);
    clk477_rrr <= clk477_rr when rising_edge(clk100);
    enable <= clk477_rrr and not clk477_rr;

    data <= data477 when (?? enable) and rising_edge(clk100);
```

The `enable477` signal is in the `clk100` domain, and `1` for one cycle of the `clk100` clock after a rising edge on the `clk477` (which is not a clock!) is detected.

If your fabric has an "enable" input on the DFFs, that is where the `enable` signal is connected to. If it doesn't, you end up with a 2:1 mux, which is also the "more likely to synthesize" form of the statement above:

```vhdl
    data_sel <= data477 when ?? enable else data;
    data <= data_sel when rising_edge(clk100);
```